# Making a vertical line in HTML/CSS under a list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a design I've made in Illustrator (I know, Lol that I've designed something I don't know how to make!)

So I've made a HTML list horizontal with a border at the bottom. I'll try and demo this visually.

### Overview Sales Settings

---

Each of the titles are also underlined (overview, sales, settings), what I would love is to get a little connecting vertical line between the underline of each word and the parent div's bottom border.

So far I've got the underline of each title (using border bottom not underline) and also the bottom border of the parent div.

What I just can't work out is how I fit a vertical line under each list item. I tried to use line break but it ends up reshaping the whole list.

Any ideas/designs would be fantastic

Thanks in advance! - Ash

Here's the link to my dropbox for the pic as my rep is too low to add a picture!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58549715/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-21%20at%2012.13.51.png

### Code

```
<div class="top-menu-two">
 <div class="top-menu-two-controls">
    <ul>
    <li>
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainOverviewColor.svg" class="svg" id="yolo"></object> 
        <span class="menuText" id="topMenuTwoOverview">Overview</span>
    </li>
    <li class="not-active">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainAgentsColor.svg" class="svg"></object> 
        <span class="menuText" id="topMenuTwoAgents">Agents</span>
    </li>
    <li class="not-active">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainSalesColor.svg" class="svg"></object> 
        <span class="menuText" id="topMenuTwoSales">Sales</span>
    </li>
    <li class="not-active">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainNewQuotationsColor.svg" class="svg"></object> 
        <span class="menuText" id="topMenuTwoNewQuotations">New Quotations</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.top-menu-two{
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
padding: 1% 0% 0% 1%;
float: right;
border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(224,34,80);
}

.top-menu-two-controls{
float: left;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Bold';
position: relative;
top: 32%;
margin-left: 20px;
}  

.top-menu-two-controls ul{
padding-left: 0;
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 20px;
}
.top-menu-two-controls li{
display: inline;
margin-right: 10px;
} 

#topMenuTwoOverview{
border-bottom: solid 3px rgb(224,34,80);
}

#topMenuTwoAgents{
border-bottom: solid 3px rgb(64,143,221);
}

#topMenuTwoSales{
border-bottom: solid 3px rgb(224,224,36);
}

#topMenuTwoNewQuotations{
border-bottom: solid 3px rgb(34,127,20);
}

.svg{
display: inline;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.menuText{
position: relative;
top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your markup/code that you made until now

Comment: Also if possible to attach an illustrator screen shot:)

Comment: @Pyere you'll find the pic on the link provided - hope this helps

Comment: SO is here to answer questions about your markup but SO is not here to write markup for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rob - Markup added now, thanks

Comment: @AshHogarth, I have updated my answer to match your image and code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm totally guessing at your html structure as you haven't provided it, but if it is something like a list (as it seems to be a nav) then you could use the after element to create the bottom line:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Overview</li>
  <li>Sales</li>
  <li>Settings</li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

Given your code I would first change it so the ids are on the `li`s instead of the `span` and then you can use the following:

```css
.top-menu-two {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1% 0% 0% 1%;
  float: right;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(224, 34, 80);
}
.top-menu-two-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Bold';
  position: relative;
  top: 32%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.top-menu-two-controls ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.top-menu-two-controls li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.top-menu-two-controls li .menuText:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 12px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
.top-menu-two-controls li.not-active .menuText:after {
    display:none;
}
.top-menu-two-controls .menuText {
  position:relative;
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
}
#topMenuTwoOverview .menuText:after,
#topMenuTwoOverview .menuText {
  border-color: rgb(224, 34, 80);
}
#topMenuTwoAgents .menuText:after,
#topMenuTwoAgents .menuText {
  border-color: rgb(64, 143, 221);
}
#topMenuTwoSales .menuText:after,
#topMenuTwoSales .menuText {
  border-color: rgb(224, 224, 36);
}
#topMenuTwoNewQuotations .menuText:after,
#topMenuTwoNewQuotations .menuText {
  border-color: rgb(34, 127, 20);
}
.svg {
  display: inline;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.menuText {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu-two">
  <div class="top-menu-two-controls">
    <ul>
      <li id="topMenuTwoOverview">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainOverviewColor.svg" class="svg" id="yolo"></object>
        <span class="menuText">Overview</span>
      </li>
      <li id="topMenuTwoAgents" class="not-active">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainAgentsColor.svg" class="svg"></object>
        <span class="menuText">Agents</span>
      </li>
      <li id="topMenuTwoSales" class="not-active">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainSalesColor.svg" class="svg"></object>
        <span class="menuText">Sales</span>
      </li>
      <li id="topMenuTwoNewQuotations" class="not-active">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="MainNewQuotationsColor.svg" class="svg"></object>
        <span class="menuText">New Quotations</span>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to play with the height of the `li:after` element depending on the font size and line-spacing

Comment: Yeah I've slightly altered little things but this is great, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I deleted the answer i posted.But please keep in mind it was not intended at all to look like i am stealing your answer.. Anyway Sorry Again @Pete

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `ul` container with a `border-bottom` property.

Inside each `li`, you can make a `div` below the text with `margin auto`, or `:after` pseudo on the li, with transparency and a fixed height and `1px width` for `border-left/border-right` and when click on some of those, with javascript/jquery, give the color.